# Azure alwaysOn is not loading MEAN app on server restart

Tags: angularjs, node.js, azure, alwayson

I have a MEAN stack application hosted on Azure with the alwaysOn setting, but this doesn't seem to start the node process without a manual http call.

This is fine but not ideal for front end tasks but killer for a daily task that needs to be executed.

Has anyone encountered this and are there any solutions?

AlwaysOn configuration or something?

Answer (score 0):

alwayson would hit your webapp every few minutes. what do you mean by it doesn't load actual app ?

check if your node.exe process is active in process explorer at kudu console.

kudu console : http://**yourwebapp_name**.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole

Comment: I think that's the issue, the node process doesn't start until I manually make an http call.

Comment: Your always on option would only hit root url http://yourwebapp_name.azurewebsites.net/. Does your root url hits nodejs ? . you can also change that in web.config file

Comment: Yes, it does, I've just retested and I can see the AlwaysOn call going through, but nodejs only loads if I manually hit the root URL.